# Appending to clipboard

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, append, clipboard

I feel like I have been asking a lot of questions the last couple days but I really need help with this one. First of its my 3rd day writing code and python is the language of choice that I chose to learn to code. 
OK I made this converter that converts units of measurement from mm to inches (and also converts surface finishes) I then want it to copy the converted number (taken out to the third decimal place) to the clipboard so I can paste it in another program. I am trying to do this using tkinter but I keep getting the error message

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Pygrams\Converter.py", line 104, in <module>
    clipboard_append(final_form)

NameError: name 'clipboard_append' is not defined
```

Here is the code (only posting the part I am having trouble with) im using (assume that variables such as Results are defined elsewhere.

```
from tkinter import Tk
final_form = ("%.3f" % Results)
final_form2 = str(final_form)
r = Tk()
r.withdraw()
r.clipboard_clear()
clipboard_append(finalform2)
r.destroy()
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `clipboard_append` is `r` method. So...

Answer (score 2):

You're calling `clipboard_append(finalform2)` when you should be calling `r.clipboard_append(finalform2)`

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I figure out my problem shortly after I posted this.